# What's the meaning of Web Page life-cycle?

Tags: c#, asp.net, lifecycle, page-lifecycle

I'm new to C# and ASP.NET. I hear a lot about application and/or web page life-cycle.
I want to know what's the meaning of this?

Comment: I want to say thank you for your replies.

Comment: Understanding the page lifecycle will make your ASP.NET development MUCH more enjoyable (it sure did for me)!  You're already on the right track by asking about it.

Comment: Google tells all: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page lifecycle is the sequence of events that are invoked in an ASP.NET Page Request.

This is documented in great detail [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

As you tagged your question with ASP.NET, here goes the mandatory doc:

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

> When an ASP.NET page runs, the page goes through a life cycle (stages) in which
>   it performs a series of processing steps. These include
>   initialization, instantiating controls, restoring and maintaining
>   state, running event handler code, and rendering. It is important for
>   you to understand the page life cycle so that you can write code at
>   the appropriate life-cycle stage for the effect you intend.

Answer (score 1):

Web Page lifecycle is simply **a sequence of events** that happen between the request (hitting the page) and response (returning data to user).

You can find more info about that here:

- [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227435.aspx)
- [Article on 15seconds about ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020102.htm)
- [Most common ASP.NET life cycle events - PDF reference card](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/aspnet-life-cycles-events.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The web page life-cycle refers to the process and events that get fired for a page when it goes from a request to a rendered page.

Here is a link to an overview:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One of the resources I still use is the [MSDN article (ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx):

> When an ASP.NET page runs, the page goes through a life cycle in which
>   it performs a series of processing steps. These include
>   initialization, instantiating controls, restoring and maintaining
>   state, running event handler code, and rendering. It is important for
>   you to understand the page life cycle so that you can write code at
>   the appropriate life-cycle stage for the effect you intend.